# executing python scripts in server

Tags: python, three.js, cgi, .obj

I have developed an application, the system allows to upload two different types of files (.obj and .mtl). These files are later needed by three.js to display a 3d-model. Unfortunately, three.js do not take .obj or .mtl directly to render the model. These files, .obj and .mtl should be converted into .js (json) in-order to be acceptable for three.js.

I have researched over the internet and found that the .obj file can be converted to .js with the help of converter convert_obj_three.py.

I am able to run the above converter in command prompt in desktop to convert .obj into .js. But what I am looking is to execute this python converter in the server itself.

I have come accross CGI stuff, but still can't grasp the idea behind it. 
So basically my question is, how to execute python scripts in the server and store its output. (In my case the output would be the converted file [something.js]).

Comment: Did you try `THREE.OBJLoader()` and `THREE.OBJMTLLoader()`?